# Want result without Exp and Log functions

Tags: equation-solving

This is what I tried.

```
Solve[((k^(1 - β) (n + δk))/sk)^(1/γ) == ((k^β sh)/(n + δh))^(1/(1 - γ)), k]
```

I get the following result

> ```
> {{k -> 
>     E^((-γ Log[sh] + (-1 + γ) Log[sk] + γ Log[n + δh] - (-1 + γ) Log[n + δk])/
>       (-1 + β + γ))}}
> ```

If I calculate the solution manually, I get a representation without Euler Number and Logs. How can I find such a representation in Mathematica?

Comment: sk and sh are variables or s is multiplied with k and h respectively?

Comment: sk and sh are variables ant not multiplied with k and h respectively

Answer (score 3):

You'll likely soon see many more efficient ways to perform the simplification but here's one way:

```
FullSimplify[k /. 
  ExpandAll[Solve[((k^(1 - β) (n + δk))/sk)^(1/γ) == 
    ((k^β sh)/(n + δh))^(1/(1 - γ)), k][[1]]] /. Exp[a_ Log[z_] + c_] -> z^a Exp[c]]

(* sh^(-(γ/(-1 + β + γ))) sk^((-1 + γ)/(-1 + β + γ))*
   (n + δh)^(γ/(-1 + β + γ)) (n + δk)^(-1 + β/(-1 + β + γ)) *)
```

or

$$\text{sh}^{-\frac{\gamma }{\beta +\gamma -1}} \text{sk}^{\frac{\gamma -1}{\beta +\gamma -1}} (\text{$\delta $h}+n)^{\frac{\gamma }{\beta +\gamma -1}} (\text{$\delta $k}+n)^{\frac{\beta }{\beta +\gamma -1}-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function that makes `Log` and `Exp` more costly as the value  of [ComplexityFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) :

```
expr = E^((-γ Log[sh] + (-1 + γ) Log[sk] + γ Log[n + δh] - 
     (-1 + γ) Log[n + δk])/(-1 + β + γ))

cf[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Log | _Exp, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]

simplified = FullSimplify[exp, ComplexityFunction -> cf]
```

> sh^(-(γ/(-1 + β + γ))) sk^((-1 + γ)/(-1 + β + γ))(n + δh)^(γ/(-1 + β + γ))(n + δk)^(-1 + β/(-1 + β + γ))

```
simplified // TeXForm
```

> $\text{sh}^{-\frac{\gamma }{\beta +\gamma -1}} \text{sk}^{\frac{\gamma -1}{\beta +\gamma -1}}
>    (\text{$\delta $h}+n)^{\frac{\gamma }{\beta +\gamma -1}} (\text{$\delta $k}+n)^{\frac{\beta
>    }{\beta +\gamma -1}-1}$